# Will Ubuntu Desktop work on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberrypi, distro-recommendation

I was just wondering if Ubuntu Desktop will work on a Raspberry Pi 3, or if I have to use a distribution that is made specifically for the device.

Comment: Ubuntu provides multiple products for the raspberry pi; have you looked?    Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Your question is outside of this site's on-topic; see my prior comment; but please don't forget *architecture* as it relates.  Ubuntu is produced for armhf, arm64, i386, amd64, ppc64el, s390x & more (*support varies on release & product*) with only 2 being suitable for a r.pi; so don't forget the architecture involved.

Comment: My RPi3 works great with Kodi, My RPi4 works great with ubuntu-20.04-desktop-arm64.

Comment: My question would be: Did anyone try? Before I waste my time trying.  I wouldn't mind if it runs slowly or if I need to disable some features. What makes it consume more than 1 GB?

Comment: You can use the *lighter* flavors on all Raspberry Pi's.  eg. my 2b+ has only 1GB of RAM, but runs fine on *lighter* Ubuntu flavors, using their *unofficial* images (created by the same folks who create the official, but unofficial as not built on Ubuntu infrastructure).

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu **Server** is available for all Raspberry Pi boards.

However Ubuntu Desktop is currently not supported on Raspberry Pi 3 boards. 4GB of RAM is a system requirement for Ubuntu Desktop.  The latest revision of the Raspberry Pi 3B+ only has 1GB of RAM.

You can access more information about Ubuntu's Raspberry Pi support, including tutorials and downloads, at the official site:

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi